# nginx redirect an internal ssl link to an non-ssl external url link

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I've got my website https `example.com` that has links to http `another.com`. How can I redirect any requests for the external url from https to http?

```
https://example.com -> http://another.com
```

The problem is that the external links tries to use https and it needs to be http.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
server {
   listen 443;
   server_name www.example.com;
   rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.another.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```